# Can't get Web Audio API to work with iOS 11 Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

So iOS 11 Safari was supposed to add support for the Web Audio API, but it still doesn't seem to work with this javascript code:

```
//called on page load
get_user_media = get_user_media || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;  
get_user_media = get_user_media || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
get_user_media.call(navigator, { "audio": true }, use_stream, function () { });
function use_stream(stream){
    var audio_context = new AudioContext();
    var microphone = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    window.source = microphone; // Workaround for https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=934512
    var script_processor = audio_context.createScriptProcessor(1024, 1, 1);
    script_processor.connect(audio_context.destination);
    microphone.connect(script_processor);
    //do more stuff which involves processing the data from user's microphone...
}
```

I copy pasted most of this code, so I only have a cursory understanding of it. I know that it's supposed to (and does, on other browsers) capture the user's microphone for further processing. I know that the code breaks on the `var audio_context = new AudioContext();` line (as in, no code after that is run), but don't have any error messages cause I don't have a mac which is required to debug iOS Safari (apple die already >_<) Anyone know what's going on and/or how to fix it?

e: forgot to mention that I looked it up and apparently I need the keyword "webkit" before using Web Audio API in Safari, but making it `var audio_context = new webkitAudioContext();` doesn't work either

Comment: Change it to window.webketAudioContext

Comment: is webket a typo?

Comment: replaced ```var audio_context = new AudioContext();``` with ```var audio_context = window.webkitAudioContext;``` but doesnt seem to help

Comment: I wonder whether recording has the same problem as playing: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW4 I think you might need to run the code in response to a touch, not on page load.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@TomW was on the right track - basically the `webkitAudioContext` is suspended unless it's created in direct response to the user's tap (before you get the stream).

See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46534088/933879 for more details and a working example.

Comment: Thanks, got it working now. Needed to change AudioContext() to webkitAudioContext() and a button to resume audio_context

Comment: Interesting.  I have a button with `audioContext.resume()` in the onclick handle.  Then, when I try to play a sound, I still have no sounds.  If I examine the audio context object, its `state` property is `running`.  Is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: @AleksG: Possibly. If the state is `running`, then you're probably not hitting *this* particular issue, although it's hard to say what the actual problem is.

Comment: Yeah... I finally got it to work in Cordova using nativeaudio plugin and in safari using the above solution. It's still not working in home screen safari app though

Comment: Hum, I wonder if they put extra restrictions on home screen web apps...? Glad to hear it's working in Cordova though!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing works on mobile save to home screen apps. I issued a bug report to Apple developer. Got a response that it was a duplicate ( which means they know..no clue if or when they will actually fix it).

Comment: do you have any more recent information about this? Currently struggling with audio on an homescreen app now