# How to convert (audio) buffer to blob to replay

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, html5-audio, audio-recording, ios11

I'm struggling to record audio and replay it on mobile safari.

This source is absolutely fabulous.
[onaudioprocess not called on ios11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46363048/onaudioprocess-not-called-on-ios11/46534088#46534088)

I can see the chunk of audio data is coming...

```
// get Buffers (Essentially a Uint8Array DataView of the same Float32 values)
var chunks = []
micStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    var raw = MicrophoneStream.toRaw(chunk)
    chunks.push(raw)
});

function replay(){
    var blob = new Blob( chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/webm;codecs=opus' });
    var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = blobURL
    audio.play()
}
```

But I could not make blob to replay.

How can I convert raw audio data into blob and replay it?
And I have no idea which mineType to use neither.

if I can use MediaRecorder API,

```
var chunks = []
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
    chunks.push(event.data);
}
function replay(){
    var blob = new Blob( chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/webm;codecs=opus' });
    var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = blobURL
    audio.play()
}
```

This works on Desktop Chrome but Safari doesn't support MediaRecorder API unfortunately.

Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to Recorderjs on GitHub:
https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

The demo can record an audio as blob and playback later. It works for desktop Chrome, but not for iOS 11 Safari:
examples\example_simple_exportwav.html

With simple modification on fuction startRecording() by adding audio_context.resume(), it does work on iOS 11 Safari:

```
  function startRecording(button) {
    audio_context.resume();
    recorder && recorder.record();
    button.disabled = true;
    button.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
    __log('Recording...');
  }
```

Hope this also works for you.

tommy

Comment: You may also refer to the following, that modified for both mobile safari support & newer navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia() API:
https://github.com/tommysheu/Recorderjs